# Is there a way to combine Excel workbooks into one Master workbook within python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I would like to know if this is possible without merging all Excel workbooks into a single Worksheet within a Master workbook

(rather)

A Master workbook, containing the sheets of all the slave workbooks

[This picture shows what I'd like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo5FD.jpg)

Perhaps is there a way to use VBA script within python to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is achievable using python and pandas. You can open multiple files by sheet and simply write them to a single output document. [See the documentation here for more information](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

You'll need to change the variable names to fit your use case, but here is a generic idea:

```
mon_sheet = pd.read_excel('file_1_path.xlsx', sheetname = 'Mon')
tue_sheet = pd.read_excel('file_1_path.xlsx', sheetname = 'Tue')
wed_sheet = pd.read_excel('file_1_path.xlsx', sheetname = 'Wed')
thu_sheet = pd.read_excel('file_2_path.xlsx', sheetname = 'Thu')
fri_sheet = pd.read_excel('file_2_path.xlsx', sheetname = 'Fri')
sat_sheet = pd.read_excel('file_3_path.xlsx', sheetname = 'Sat')
sun_sheet = pd.read_excel('file_3_path.xlsx', sheetname = 'Sun')

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer: 
    mon_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Mon')
    tue_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Tue')
    wed_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Wed')
    thu_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Thu')
    fri_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Fri')
    sat_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sat')
    sun_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sun')
```

Comment: However, could you provide some clarity. I thought I could only use pandas to extract all the slave workbooks' worksheets into a single dataframe and subsequently write the dataframe onto a single worksheet. Could you confirm that is possible to use pandas to create a Masterworkbook while preserving separate worksheets?

Comment: ah I see! Thanks, appreciated.